# R shows too few digits

Tags: r, rounding, digits

I wanted to calculate that term:

```
(21000*(1.022^7-1))/(1.022-1)
```

`R` tells me, it's `157065.7`. This was my answer to a task that I had to solve. It was stated that this answer is not correct, the correct answer should be `157065.67`. Then I calculated this with my calculator on my smartphone and indeed, the solution was `157065.67034`. I am really wondering what is wrong with `R` and whether I can change some options. I've tried `options()$digits` but that's `7`, this can't be the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `options(digits = 15)`. Note that this changes globally the format. Also, the number of digits indicates all the digits (before and after the decimal separator).

Comment: Greath, thank you, I wanted to change that globally. I will accept the answer as soon as it's possible. Is every number rounded at each intermediate step?

Comment: Usually R rounds number to the nearest (up or down) and to the even side if it ends in 5 (0.35 -> 0.4)

Comment: the `digits` option does not change the *internal* precision of any of the calculations (which are done with standard 64-bit floating point math), only the number of digits printed in the output

Answer (score 4):

One option:

```r
formatC((21000*(1.022^7-1))/(1.022-1), digits = 11)
#> [1] "157065.67035"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would display more decimals.

```
print((21000*(1.022^7-1))/(1.022-1), digits=16)
[1] 157065.670346861
```

There's nothing "wrong" with R in this respect. Decisions have to be made about how to print floating point values to the console.